# Passing parameters into SQLite querys

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm currently trying to query my SQLite database using the following line of code:

```
public Cursor getExpenses(String username)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor results = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_EXPENSES + " WHERE username = " + username  , null);
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(results);
        return results;
    }
```

The problem is the parameter `username` does not get passed into the query and instead I get returned all the data in `TABLE_EXPENSES`. If I leave out the quotes, I get `no such column` error. I was thinking of escaping the double quotes on `username` but apparently after some searching it seems like you can't escape the characters on SQLite? Hence, my question: How do I pass the parameter into the query.

Comment: `+ "username"` is a raw string, not the variable you passed in

Comment: From duplicate question... Use `whereArgs = new String[] { username }`. Don't put quotes around username

Comment: My bad, was actually messing around with the code and accidentally paste my current working version with the `+ "username"` part. Updated to show what I was actually trying to achieve.

Comment: The code you have isn't wrong, but I suggest using `query` rather than `rawQuery` (lookup SQL injection). You should get `no such column` if you put quotes on the variable or not